# maven include assembly from another module into rpm

Tags: maven, rpm

I have a multi module maven project, along with the many code modules, which build standard jar files, I have one module that builds a test harness as a zip file using the maven-assembly-plugin and another module that builds the application rpm using the rpm-maven-plugin. I want to include the test harness zip file within the rpm.

Currently I'm doing the following in the rpm module:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>appn</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-harness</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    :
    <mapping>
        <directory>/opt/app/installed/${rpmSoftwareName}-${project.version}/utils</directory>
        <username>${rpmUsername}</username>
        <groupname>${rpmGroupname}</groupname>
        <filemode>0755</filemode>
        <sources>
            <source>
                <location>${project.build.directory}/../../test-harness/target/test-harness-${project.version}-dist.zip</location>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <directory>/opt/app/installed/${rpmSoftwareName}-${project.version}/lib</directory>
        <username>${rpmUsername}</username>
        <groupname>${rpmGroupname}</groupname>
        <filemode>0755</filemode>
        <dependency />
    </mapping>
```

The problem I have is the lib directory of the rpm has the test-harness and its transitive dependencies included. If I exclude the test-harness from the lib mapping I don't get the test-harness, but I do get its transitive dependencies. If I remove the test-harness as a dependency then I have to rely on the module order in the parent pom to ensure the test-harness gets built first which seems a bit weak as does relying on the relative path to include the test-harness in the mapping... there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is first not using relative paths which access other modules (../target/ etc.). Better use a dependency in the rpm-module. Define the zip file for example as a dependency with the appropriate classifier.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>project.com.domain</groupId>
     <artifactId>test-harness</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
     <classifier>dist</classifier>
     <type>zip</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After you should simply add the dependency into the rpm-configuration like the following:

```
<mapping>
  <directory>/usr/local/lib</directory>
  <filemode>750</filemode>
  <username>dumper</username>
  <groupname>dumpgroup</groupname>
  <dependency>
    <includes>
      <include>...:test-harness:dist:zip:${project.version}</include>
      <include>...</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>...</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </dependency>
</mapping>
```

I'm not 100% sure which is the exact order for the include (artifactId:classifier:type:version?).

Comment: Adding the test harness as a dependency (even with the classifier and type) still causes it and its transitive dependencies to be included in the rpm lib directory. Excluding the test-harness in the lib directory mapping just excludes the test-harness but still keeps its transitive dependencies - but I think this is the right direction

Comment: Add an exclusion at the dependencies area. That should do the trick.